# Is it safe to read past the end of an array?

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have a constructor like this:

```
MyColor(uint8 vec[]) {
r = vec[0];
g = vec[1];
b = vec[2];
a = vec[3];
}
```

But I call it like this (3 elements instead of 4):

```
uint8 tmp[] = {1,2,3};
MyColor c(tmp);
```

But now `vec[3]` is undefined... is it safe to assign this value to `a`? If not, there's no nice workaround to check if `vec[3]` is set is there?

Comment: This is not an example of a dangling pointer. Nor is it an example of saving a pointer, dangling or not. It's a buffer overrun. A dangling pointer is one that used to point somewhere valid but doesn't anymore.

Comment: My bad. I was afraid I had my terminology mixed up but I didn't know what else to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you dont want to use vector try this...

```
MyColor(uint8 (&vec)[3])
{
   r = vec[0];
   g = vec[1];
   b = vec[2];
}

MyColor(uint8 (&vec)[4])
{
   //...
}

uint8 a1[] = {1,2,3};
MyColor c1(a1);
uint8 a2[] = {1,2,3,4};
MyColor c2(a2);
uint8 a3[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
MyColor c3(a3); // error
```

you dont have to include the array's size explicitly and if you try to pass an array with wrong number of elements, compile error will be generated,

Comment: Now that's cool! Didn't know you could do that. Was trying to do that, but my syntax was wrong I guess.

Answer (score 19):

No it's not safe. It's undefined behavior as defined by the standard. It might blow the whole app up or return a random value. The workaround is to pass the size along with it, or use `vector` instead.

Comment: "undefined as defined by the standard"? ;)

Comment: @jalf Have you read the spec?  It says thing exactly like that.

Comment: @C.Ross: my (silly) point was that undefined behavior is (by definition, pun intended) not defined by the standard. It wouldn't be undefined if it was "defined by the standard". ;)

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not safe. You're reading memory that you have not allocated, and this is undefined behavior. Depending on the phase of the moon you might or might not get a segmentation fault.

To "work around" it, make sure the array you pass in has always the correct size. In your example you could do:

```
uint8 tmp[4] = {1,2,3};
MyColor c(tmp);
```

The initializer doesn't need to specify all the elements of the array that gets created, so it's ok to just initialize the first three values explicitly. The remaining values will be set to zero.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not safe. Maybe you would like to pass the coordinates as parameters to constructor and use two overloads:

```
MyColor(uint8 a, uint8 b, uint8 c, uint8 d) {
    stuff
}

MyColor(uint8 a, uint8 b, uint8 c) {
    stuff
}
```

This way you can use both

```
MyColor a(1, 2, 3);
MyColor b(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, as in C, on function arguments arrays decay into pointers. Now, depending on the semantics of the function you can use other approaches:

```
// explicit parameters (with or without default values):
mycolor( uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, uint8_t alpha = 255 );

// vector (can check length)
mycolor( std::vector<uint8_t> const & components );

// array by reference
mycolor( uint8_t (&components)[ 4 ] );
```

The first approach to me is the cleanest.

Comment: Defining a struct/class Colour (or whatever) which has the four elements is probably even better..

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It's possible this causes a segfault.

Billy3

Answer (score 1):

The shown behavior is undefined, and likely to crash down the road.

I would recommend to use vector along, and access elements using vector::at() call. That will throw an exception if went beyond alloted bounds. Ensure to reserve enough space in the vector

Answer (score 0):

It's like you'r asking if it's safe to build a house on top of a lake. One day you may wake up in the water.

In your case you may find that a dangling pointer can cause unstability and frequent crashes to the system.

If you know what a dangling pointer is you now what the risk is.

Comment: Well, if the user doesn't specify the alpha value, it's assumed he won't try using it either. But I guess the mere assignment can cause destruction.